# I have 29GB free on the sd card and only 101mb on storage,before I had 800mb and installed batman arkam,the download stopped at 91%

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Because I hadn't sufficient memory,but the files remains on mine phone but i can't find them and delete theM. On google play it says that the game isn't installed and in the phone either.How to free my phone? And other question how to use the space on sd card..? I have samsung galaxy s4 with 4.4.2 android NO ROOT

Answer (score 0):

You can use an utility such as [Disk Usage & Storage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile_infographics_tools.mydrive) or [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) which will show you graphical information of your storage usage. Once analyzed, you can sort folders by size and try to locate the particular folder. Using a file manager, I would definitely check `/Android/data` and `/Android/obb` folders. The orphaned files and folders are highly likely to be located in one of those. The external SD card storage can be used in any way you please. You can use it as the default storage for photos/videos, you can copy files on it etc.